# jquery hover changes click effects

Tags: jquery, list, click, hover

I have an unordered list as menu, with hover effects using jquery (not css because I am planning to make other changes to other elements on hover).  I applied an effect on click and disabled the hover to prevent it from changing on mouseout but i can't seem to accomplish this simple task.  The click effect doesn't change the background and I can no longer click again as it's been unbinded.

1. apply hover effect
2. apply effect to clicked item
3. remove previous effect when other item is selected

here is js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//hover
$('li').hover(function(){
   $(this).css('background-color', 'blue'); 
}, function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red'); 
});

//click
$('li').click(function(){
    $(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseout');
   $(this).css('backgrond-color', 'blue');
});
```

});

here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6GM7T/7/) link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/6GM7T/18/) --   this can be optimized, but for now, it work's as expected

```
$('li').on('click', function (e) {
    $('li').each(function () {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
        $('li').hover(function () {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
        }, function () {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
        });
    });
    $(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
    $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6GM7T/15/)

```
 $(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
```

hover is alias for mouseenter/mouseleave not mouseout.

Comment: thanks for this roasted.  how do i bind the mouseenter and mouseleave to previous button after I clicked another button?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('li').click(function () {
    $('li').not($(this)).bind('mouseenter', function () {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
    }).bind('mouseleave', function () {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    })
    $(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
    $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6GM7T/17/)

Comment: i have changed this in jsfiddle but same result.

Comment: yes, it should. and should reactivate hover when other item is clicked.

Comment: almost perfect :).. how do I bind the hover for previous selected item, after I clicked new item?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the CSS :hover selector in your stylesheet

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
ul li {
    height: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 2px;
    text-align: center;
}

ul li:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Then on click you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //click
    $('li').click(function(){
       $('ul li').css('background-color', '');
       $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
    });
});
```

Here's an updated jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SpvUJ/

Comment: thanks RHarrington, this actually works.  but am trying to use jquery for hover because i am planning to apply effects to another element outside of the list tag.

Comment: Why would your .hover jQuery not work for these "other" elements though?  The only reason you would need to use CSS on the LI elements is due to the fact that the mouseout event is fired.  This should not be the case for elements outside of the li.

Answer (score 0):

Use css classes and it becomes simpler:

```
$("li").hover(function() { $(this).addClass("hover"); }, function () { $(this).removeClass("hover"); });
$("li").click(function () { $("li.selected").removeClass("selected"); $(this).addClass("selected"); });
```

Your css:

```
li { background-color: red; }
li.selected, li.hover { background-color: blue; }
```